# Download file using Google drive api v3 in java

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I try to use google drive api v3 to download file in java with this code i get it from github from this link [this link of java file in github](https://github.com/googleworkspace/java-samples/blob/master/drive/snippets/drive_v3/src/main/java/DownloadFile.java)

```
package drive.sample;


import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    
    private static ByteArrayOutputStream downloadFile(String realFileId) throws IOException{
        /* Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
        TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity for
        guides on implementing OAuth2 for your application.*/
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
        credentials);
        
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
        requestInitializer)
        .setApplicationName("Drive samples")
        .build();
        
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            
            service.files().get(realFileId)
            .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            
            return (ByteArrayOutputStream) outputStream;
            }catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            System.err.println("Unable to move file: " + e.getDetails());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
// [END drive_download_file]
```

But when run app it show me this error

> Error :  type of HttpCredentialsAdapter (com. google . auth.Credentials) is erroneous

How i can solve this problem ?

Comment: @DaImTo yes for android

Comment: The code works as intended. Your error is most likely due to a typo (note the capitalized S in your error log) or due to invalid credentials.